# how to get details of all the running apps in a pcf space after login to pcf via cli mode

Tags: command-line-interface, pcf

```
cf login -a api_end_point -u -p -o org -s space
```

Once logged in i need to get the running apps info under a particular space. I tried below but no luck

```
cf services
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

try with

> cf apps

instead of services... cf apps will show you all the applications name, requested state   instances   memory   disk   urls details